# Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm. Nothing else worked

Tags: c#, string, encryption, base64

So after googling for well over 2 hours, I haven't really found any working solution to this problem. I'm trying to encrypt a link but it keeps showing me this one error every time.

**Declaration**:

```
                        if (F != null)
                        {
                            text = text.Replace("string license", "string license = @\"" + Convert.ToBase64String(F) + "\"");
                        }
```

**Encryption**:

```
        {
            try
            {
                Aes aes = new AesManaged
                {
                    Key = new byte[] {},
                    IV = new byte[16],
                    Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                    Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
                };
                ICryptoTransform crypto;
                crypto = aes.CreateEncryptor();
                return crypto.TransformFinalBlock(message, 0, message.Length); //return encrypted value
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues I don't like to comment. Try the code in this link as a basis  for your tests (disclaimer: I'm the author) https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/AesCbc256StringEncryption/AesCbc256StringEncryption_Full.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your Key needs to be 16 bytes long. new byte[] {} will create a Key that is 0 bytes long